# Read ORC files directly from Spark shell

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am having issues reading an ORC file directly from the Spark shell. Note: running Hadoop 1.2, and Spark 1.2, using pyspark shell, can use spark-shell (runs scala).

I have used this resource http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.2.4/Apache_Spark_Quickstart_v224/content/ch_orc-spark-quickstart.html .

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hiveCtx = HiveContext(sc)

inputRead = sc.hadoopFile("hdfs://user@server:/file_path",
classOf[inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat],
classOf[outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat])
```

I get an error generally saying wrong syntax. One time, the code seemed to work, I used just the 1st of three arguments passed to hadoopFile, but when I tried to use

```
inputRead.first()
```

the output was RDD[nothing, nothing]. I don't know if this is because the inputRead variable did not get created as an RDD or if it was not created at all.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: hi , i am novice to python, but in scala ,the notation to read ORC file will be like this : sc.hadoopFile(ORC_FILE_PATH,classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct]) ; try adding 4 parameters like this in python

Comment: ORC file newly supported in Spark 1.4. So for that you can use spark's latest version

Comment: Thanks! I read a Hive table stored as ORC via HiveContext into and worked with the dataFrame and querying against that. @kaushal I think there is a jira for that, not necessarily integrate in Spark 1.4 (not completely sure)

Answer (score 12):

In Spark 1.5, I'm able to load my ORC file as:

```
val orcfile = "hdfs:///ORC_FILE_PATH"
val df = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load(orcfile)
df.show
```

Comment: How to add multiple path to load from

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code, it's working for me.

```
val LoadOrc = spark.read.option("inferSchema", true).orc("filepath")
LoadOrc.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also add the multiple path to read from

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/aks/input1/*","hdfs://localhost:8020/aks/input2/*/part-r-*.orc")
```