# Spark Shell Import Fine, But Throws Error When Referencing Classes

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am a beginner in Apache Spark, so please excuse me if this is quite trivial.

Basically, I was running the following import in `spark-shell`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SQLContext, DataFrameReader}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.{OrcInputFormat,OrcStruct};
import org.apa‌​che.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
...

val rdd = sc.hadoopFile(path, 
    classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFor‌​mat], 
    classOf[NullWritable], 
    classOf[OrcStruct],
    1)
```

The import statements up till OrcInputFormat works fine, with the exception that:

`error: object apa‌​che is not a member of package org
         import org.apa‌​che.hadoop.io.NullWritable;`

It does not make sense, if the import statement before goes through without any issue.

In addition, when referencing `OrcInputFormat`, I was told:

`error: type OrcInputFor‌​mat is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc`

It seems strange that import for `OrcInputFormat` to work (I assume it works, since no error is thrown), but then the above error message turns up. Basically, I am trying to read ORC files from S3.

I am also looking at what have I done wrong, and why this happens.

**What I have done:**

1. I have tried running `spark-shell` with the `--jars` option, and tried importing `hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar` (My current version of Spark is 1.6.1, compiled with Hadoop 2.6)
2. `val df = sqlContext.read.format("orc").load(PathToS3)`, as referred by ([Read ORC files directly from Spark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792494/read-orc-files-directly-from-spark-shell)). I have tried variations of S3, S3n, S3a, without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 non-printing characters between `org.ape` and `che` in the last import, most certainly due to a copy paste :

```
import org.apa&#x200C;&#x200B;che.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
```

Just rewrite the last import statement and it will work. Also you don't need these semi-colons.

You have the same problem with OrcInputFormat :

```
error: type OrcInputFor&#x200C;&#x200B;mat is not member of package org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc
```

That's funny, in the mobile version of Stackoverflow we can cleary see those non-printing characters :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was a pretty sneaky one... Although this does not appear to resolve `error: type OrcInputFor‌​mat is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc`, unfortunately...

Comment: see my update, same problem and same solution ! Please accept/vote my answer if it helped you, thanks