# Reading from S3 Throws NoSuchMethodError, specifically, SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Tags: scala, maven, amazon-s3

I am trying to read ORC file from S3, using `spark-shell`, following the guide below:

[Read ORC files directly from Spark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792494/read-orc-files-directly-from-spark-shell)

I have defined the path to be `s3a://...`

Unfortunately, this causes the following exception to be thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:56)
    ...
```

I have imported the jar file in spark-shell through the following command in an attempt to rectify the missing method, but to no avail.

`spark-shell --jars /home/admin/Downloads/httpclient4.5.2.jar,
            /home/admin/Downloads/httpclient-4.5.2.jar,
            /home/admin/Downloads/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar,
            /home/admin/Downloads/hadoop-aws-2.6.0.jar,
            /home/admin/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.41.jar`

I am suspecting that spark has its own copy of `SSLConnectionSocketFactory`, as I was able to import `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` even while excluding the `--jars` option.

Other than creating a maven project, (which is another headache, as I am having problems with it), is there anyway I can resolve this error where Spark claims that SSLConnectionSocketFactory could not be initialised?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that some Spark versions are not compatible with some AWS versions. For example, with Spark 1.6 and hadoop 2.6 I had to use AWS 1.10.77 ( I was having the same problem).

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to get that to work. @carlos_technogi, how do you determine which version of Spark goes with which version of AWS?

Comment: I spent a lot of time, first checking which version of httpclient and and commons-httpclient had that method with that parameter, and then trying to find a version of hadoop and aws that worked with those versions. It worked, but it was a pian... I actually ended up reading the files with Kinesis instead of S3 with Hadoop and found it was way way faster...